# Complex Schema with subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

UPDATE:

Currently i have this schema:

```
var Schema = new schema ({
    name: String,
    type: { type: String },
    date: { type: Date },
    descrip: String,
});
```

But i use this schema for generate 2 documents:

```
THE A TYPE ({
    name: 'A',
    type: 'TYPE_B',
    date: { type: Date },
    descrip: 'DESC_A',
});

THE B TYPE ({
    name: 'B',
    type: 'TYPE_B',
    date: { type: Date },
    descrip: 'DESC_B',
});
```

The name, type and descrip are always the same in the A and B types, the only thing that changes is the date field, so i was thinking, how can i improve this? How can i insert several dates in the same schema, instead of create always an document with the same name, type and descrip values?

So i am trying to create a schema inside other schema, but i dont know if this is possible, it is?

I was trying like this:

```
var mainSchema = new schema ({
    name: String,
    type: { type: String },
    date: [ dateSchema ],
    descrip: String,
});

var dateSchema = new Schema ({
    date: {
     type: Date
    }  
});
```

What i want, is create two mainSchema, type a and type b, and insert dates inside...

Am i doing this right? How can i achieve my goals?

I am searching for a full answer with good explanation, that's why the bounty. I don't accept +/- answers.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample document that shows how you want it to look?  It's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: just a sec @JohnnyHK

Comment: done @JohnnyHK.. can u understand now?

Answer (score 6):

To create a record with multiple dates you can use array of Dates.

```
var mainSchema = new schema ({
name: String,
type: { type: String },
dates: [Date],
descrip: String,
});
```

The documents will be as follows

```
THE A TYPE ({
name: 'A',
type: 'TYPE_B',
dates: ["2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z","2015-01-22T14:56:59.301Z"],
descrip: 'DESC_A',
});

THE B TYPE ({
name: 'B',
type: 'TYPE_B',
dates: ["2015-01-22T14:56:59.301Z","2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z"],
descrip: 'DESC_B',
});
```

Reference: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

For **saving** the document you can use like.

```
exports.save = function(req,res){
var test = new newSchema;  // new object for newSchema domain.
test.name= req.body.name;
test.type= req.body.type;
test.desc= req.body.desc;
if(req.body.date){
    req.body.forEach(function(date){  // For every element of date from client.
        test.date.push(date)  // This pushes each and every date given from the client into the date array.
    })
}
test.save(function (saveErr, saved) {  // Saves the new document into db.
    if (saveErr) {
        console.log(saveErr)
        return;
    }
    res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(saved);
});
};
```

For **Update** you can use like.

```
exports.update = function(req,res){  
newSchema.findOne({name: 'B'},function(err,test){  // Finds a record with name:'B' and stores in test the same can be done for name:'A'.
    if(test){
        if(req.body.date){
            req.body.forEach(function(date){
                test.date.push(date)  // pushes dates into existing test document (update).
            })
        }
        test.save(function (saveErr, saved) {  // Saves (updates) the document.
            if (saveErr) {
                console.log(saveErr)
                return;
            }
            res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(saved);
        });
    }
});
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am offering a bounty, could u be more specific? How can i insert new dates without delete the older?

Comment: waiting.. @SUNDARRAJANK

Comment: Please look at the docs: [Mongoose - API for arrays](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types-array-js) - maybe it could be some help, but I also think @SUNDARRAJANK 's idea seems to be good and simple.

Comment: check the updated answer.  currently the date in the domain is a document you need to change it into an array and push multiple dates into it.

Comment: any other thing needed..?

Answer (score 1):

If your code write down in one section it will look like this

```
var mainSchema = new schema ({
    name: String,
    type: { type: String },
    date: [ {date: { type: Date } } ],
    descrip: String,
});
```

I think that's wrong. Also you don't need to creat `new schema` like this, you can use just `{}` in your code http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp . I think correct code must look like this:

```
var mainSchema = {
 name: string,
 date: {},
 descrip: string
}
```

And then push into 'date' your dates. Good luck.

======================== HOW TO USE =======================

Sorry for delay. You can use `mainSchema.date.date_1 = date;` or you can chang `date: {},` to `date: [],` and use `mainSchema.date.push(date)` depend on your needs.

Comment: i don't know if i understood your answer.. how push the new entry date to the schema?

Comment: can you improve your answer @winston86?